# Swift4 Error on High Sierra, can't resolve symbol

Tags: swift, cocoa, macos-high-sierra

I've got this prefpane made in Swift and Cocoa... Yesterday I migrated it to Swift 4 as-per-the-migration guide and after some initial pains everything appeared to be working perfectly.

I did this on Sierra, running Xcode 9.0 with the latest SDK.

Problem is, at least two people running High Sierra tell me the pane is not running at all for them. From attempting to run it from the command line, this is the reported error:

```
2017-09-27 23:00:59.921 System Preferences[3047:337095] Error loading /Users/luckman212/Library/PreferencePanes/SwiftDefaultApps.prefPane/Contents/MacOS/SwiftDefaultApps:  dlopen(/Users/luckman212/Library/PreferencePanes/SwiftDefaultApps.prefPane/Contents/MacOS/SwiftDefaultApps, 265): can't resolve symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSError in /Users/luckman212/Library/PreferencePanes/SwiftDefaultApps.prefPane/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib because dependent dylib #1 could not be loaded in /Users/luckman212/Library/PreferencePanes/SwiftDefaultApps.prefPane/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
2017-09-27 23:00:59.922 System Preferences[3047:337095] [NSPrefPaneBundle instantiatePrefPaneObject] (/Users/luckman212/Library/PreferencePanes/SwiftDefaultApps.prefPane): principalClass is nil.
2017-09-27 23:01:00.072 System Preferences[3047:337095]  ### AE 1868656752 sender's PID is 3047 (System Preferences)
```

I haven't upgraded yet and have no way to do it at present, even if I was so-inclined. Haas anybody faced this issue, and/or know the cause for it?

Comment: I am working on a screen saver and I get a similar linker error when I try to start it from System Preferences. I have no idea how to fix it. I use High Sierra.

Comment: I think I saw you post about it on developer.apple.com? While I think I understand the explanation given there (which was essentially you're doing it badwrong®, don't use Swift; i.e. not very helpful), I think this might be a bug in High Sierra, because it for sure does not happen on earlier versions of the OS.

Comment: Hi, I think it is both a bug in High Sierra and macOS doesn't really support  screen savers in Swift well. Here is a similar project and as I understand they also use some hack to make it running: https://github.com/JohnCoates/Aerial/issues/4

Comment: Have you also contacted Apple stuff? You are working on a prefpane not on a screen saver. Even if it is a badwrong to create screen saver in Swift, your issue can be really a bug only and they may fix it.

Comment: Having the exact same issue here -- did anyone figure it out?

Comment: I would love to see a solution! Please dupe https://openradar.appspot.com/25569037

Comment: Just created a simple preferences pane sample project in Swift (https://github.com/klaas/QlaasSwiftPreferencesPane) and reported the bug to Apple myself (http://openradar.appspot.com/35648336)

Comment: I've tested this project on my iMac Mid 2011 and I've no problem - no errors, all works fine. Do you have a regular mac or an hackintosh?

Comment: Did you try to "Embed Swift Runtime Libraries" in the Build Settings?

Comment: Try one more option, create new project with different name. Just copy sources to new project. If configuration required, do. Finally run and see what will happen.

Comment: Forget to mention in my comment: This only occurs on High Sierra! On Sierra everything works fine.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano Are you on High Sierra? I'm running V10.13.1 (17B48). It's a regular MacBook Pro (Late 2016 with Touchbar)

Comment: Yes. Runtime libraries are embedded (it wouldn't run at all otherwise) and in Sierra it works fine both on real macs and in hackintoshes (which is not really a surprise. A hackintosh is not arcane magic).  In high Sierra it just won't.

Comment: I'm sorry Klaas, I've forgot to mentioned I've tried it to Sierra 10.12.6. @Gregorio Litenstein About hackintosh is not arcane magic if you know how to built it : you should know that any macOS was never based on AMD CPUs but someone can built and install HSierra on AMD, so I would be careful to underestimate some parameters

Comment: Indeed, it's an Apple bug. I created a new prefpane project, built => it installs. I added Swift => built doesn't install. I checked rpath and link lines in Terminal, I ensured swift libraries are copied, I manually linked AppKit. Nothing helped. Then I removed Swift and rebuilt => works.

Answer (score 1):

Some code angel at Apple fixed the specific issue in one of the latest dot releases of macOS High Sierra! Yay!

I'm on the latest macOS 10.13.4 (17E199), Xcode 9.3 (9E145) and Swift 4.1 (swiftlang-902.0.48 clang-902.0.37.1).

My simple test project https://github.com/klaas/QlaasSwiftScreenSaver, the famous Aerial saver
https://github.com/JohnCoates/Aerial/pull/420‌ and my Emoji Saver https://emojisaver.eu‌ work again!

The issues described by Quinn at https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/268934 still exist in general, but at least with only one (used) Swift plugin/saver within the System Preferences everything is fine.

Comment: And Hallelujah!